# Jest/Enzyme can't find getState function in configured store

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I have just begun writing tests for our application and am stumped by redux. This is the structure right now.

**Test**

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
const initialState = require("./testUtils/testUtils")

const mockStore = configureStore(applyMiddleware(thunk), initialState);
describe('<Link/>', () => {
    test("Renders a link tag", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(
             <Provider store={mockStore}> <Link href="" /> </Provider>
        ).dive({context: {mockStore}})

        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
})
```

**Component**

```
const Link = props => {
    const { href, ...rest } = props
    const absoluteLink = useAbsoluteLink(href)
    return <MaterialLink href={absoluteLink} {...rest} />
}
```

**useAbsoluteLink**

```
export default link => {
    const hostName = useSelector(state => state.pageData.hostName)
    if (typeof link != 'undefined'
        && hostName
        && link.charAt(0) != '#'
        && !/^https?:\/\//i.test(link)
        && !/^\/\//.test(link)
    ) {
        link = hostName + link
    }

    return link
}
```

**Error**

```
● <Link/> › Renders a link tag

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined

      24 | 
      25 |     test("Renders a link tag", () => {
    > 26 |         const wrapper = shallow(
         |                         ^
      27 |              <Provider strore={mockStore}> <Link href="" /> </Provider>
      28 |         ).dive({context: {mockStore}})
      29 |
```

I have tried everything I've seen while doing research but nothing has solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you've missed `mockStore` invocation. As of [doc](https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/redux-mock-store#synchronous-actions), from `configureStore` you get function `nockStore` which you should call again, passing fake store to it.

```
// Initialize mockstore with empty state
const initialState = { pageData: { hostName: 'some-host-name' } }
const store = mockStore(initialState)
```

Resulting `store` you should pass to `Provider`